Podman won run sh script in mounted drive - No such file or directory
I have a make file that builds a python alpine container, and then trys to run a script 'package.sh' in the local directory that has been mounted as /app
but when I run my make command, it is presenting the following error
{"msg":"exec container process (missing dynamic library?) `/app/local-scripts/package.sh`: No such file or directory","level":"error","time":"2024-11-15T06:19:35.564744Z"}
make: *** [Makefile:6: package-local] Error 1

I can't seem to figure out why it cant find the file.
when I launch the container in interactive mode, I can see the 'package.sh' script via the app mount all ok
commands in makefile:
@podman build -t python-alpine-local -f local-scripts/Dockerfile .
@podman run -v ${PWD}:/app localhost/python-alpine-local /app/local-scripts/package.sh

commands in my Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.12-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add zip
RUN apk add libpq-dev
RUN apk add build-base
RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip

I'm hoping to get the make file to successfully run the podman container along with the 'package.sh' script

Solved the issue.
I issued the run command for my container to enter interactive mode
podman run -it -v "${PWD}:/app" localhost/python-alpine-local /bin/sh
and executed shell command:
/bin/sh /app/local-scripts/package.sh
And got odd output
Did some googling to suggest these errors typically happen when a script has Windows-style line endings (CRLF).
When a script with CRLF line endings is run in a Unix environment, the shell sees the extra \r character as part of the command, which results in the : not found error.

I then ran the following command to remove them
sed -i 's/\r//' /app/local-scripts/package.sh
then ran the script again and it worked.
